# Are there parliamentary republics where Supreme Court appointments are decided exclusively by the Parliament and the government?

Tags: democracy, israel, supreme-court

In Israel, many political figures on the right (among them outgoing Minister of Justice [Ayelet Shaked](https://www.timesofisrael.com/right-moves-against-supreme-court-as-shaked-presents-plan-for-legal-upheaval/) and Zehut party leader and parliamentary hopeful Moshe Feiglin) say that "all over the world" judicial appointments are made exclusively by elected officials and they propose to apply that system to Israel also.

I know that in the US judicial appointments are a political issue, but the American system is more presidential than parliamentary, so I would like to ask if there are examples, more akin to Israel, where judicial appointments are exclusively political.

Comment: Why republics? Surely constitutional monarchies should also be good for your question?

Comment: Related question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/33720/judges-appointment-mechanisms/ although not as focued on your issue as you'd probably like. But the answer to your is mostly NO.

Comment: And the data in a question of mine https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34272/are-there-some-studies-which-measure-the-level-of-politicization-of-courts-in-a probably helps too.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons yes, I did not think of constitutional monarchies but they would also be good

Comment: There is a big difference between a decision 'made by elected officials' and 'being political'. In the UK and Canada judicial appointments are made by the government, but are supposed to be apolitical.